# Ports used by Online Email Accounts such as Yahoo Mail, Gmail etc

Tags: email, smtp, port, pop3

Let us say that I send an email using Yahoo Mail or Gmail.  Can this email be intercepted using a packet sniffer?

On which port does the email travel?  HTTP, SMTP, POP3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you type the email in your webbrowser, it is transferred using **HTTP(S)** to the service provider (yahoo/google)
- when you click send, the message gets sent via **SMTP** to the target mail server
- when the recipient downloads the mail it is usually transferred via **POP3** or **IMAP** to his mail client (or if he reads it in a webbrowser, then it's **HTTP(S)** again)

for all these protocols, there are "plain" and "encrypted" variants:

examples:

- HTTP -> *HTTPS*
- SMTP -> *SMTP with TLS*
- POP3 -> *POP3S*
- IMAP -> *IMAPS (or IMAP with TLS)*

for someone with access to the source or target system it is always possible to intercept the traffic and read it, even if the encrypted protocol is used. someone inbetween the two systems (for example a router operator) could intercept the packets, but usually not read the content if the stream is encrypted.